# Symmetric Relation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm working with relations and I want to find whether a relation is symmetric.

To find that a relation is symmetric, we need to find two tuples such that: `[(a,b), (b,a)]`.

This is what I've got so far:

```
simmetry:: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [a]
simmetry [] = []
simmetry (x:xs)
            | (fst x `elem` map snd xs) && (snd x `elem` map fst xs) = fst x : (simmetry xs)
            | otherwise = simmetry xs
```

What this function does is, it grabs a tuple `x` and checks that it finds its first element in another tuple as the second position, as well as checking that the second element is in another tuple as the first position.

However I'm missing out on the part where I have to check that the other tuple is the same one for both conditions. With my code, something like this: `[(a,b),(b,c),(d,a)]` would work.

P.D: `simmetry` returns `[a]` for testing purposes.

I'm out of ideas, any tips are highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but can't you just do `| (snd x, fst x) ˋelemˋ xs`?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what @Rik Van Toor said:

```
simmetry:: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [a]
simmetry [] = []
simmetry (x:xs)
            | (snd x, fst x) `elem` xs = fst x : (simmetry xs)
            | otherwise = simmetry xs
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to check is: for *every* tuple `(x,y)` in the list, `(y,x)` should also be present. You can express that quite directly in Haskell:

```
isSymmetric :: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> Bool
isSymmetric l = all (\(x,y) -> (y,x)`elem`l) l
```

This is actually doing some redundant work because it always also goes over `(x,y)` itself, which your not really interested in, but it doesn't really matter. However it's a good exercise to design this in a way so it *doesn't* go over the element itself; for this it's helpful to use an auxiliary function

```
foci :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
```

witht the behaviour

```
foci [p,q,r] ≡ [(p,[q,r]), (q,[p,r]), (r,[p,q])]
```

Then you left with an `all` over the `foci` of the input list, i.e.

```
isSymmetric = all _ . foci
```